# How to access Json data of format "key:key":"value" using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, json

I have the following json data:

```
"items": [
{
"creator": "John doe",
"title": "Third blog story",
"link": "https://medium.com/@doe115237/third-blog-story-35916b5666be?source=rss-af5ade1fb984------2",
"pubDate": "Tue, 19 Nov 2019 11:18:44 GMT",
"content:encoded": "<p>Nothing but stupid Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic consectetur laboriosam atque recusandae quis unde fuga, voluptate neque tempore enim.</p><figure><img alt=\"\" src=\"https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1024/0*iIJoKQM1yHyjbJz3\" /><figcaption>Photo by <a href=\"https://unsplash.com/@emilep?utm_source=medium&amp;utm_medium=referral\">Émile Perron</a> on <a href=\"https://unsplash.com?utm_source=medium&amp;utm_medium=referral\">Unsplash</a></figcaption></figure><p>Nothing else, sorry to waste your time!</p><img src=\"https://medium.com/_/stat?event=post.clientViewed&referrerSource=full_rss&postId=35916b5666be\" width=\"1\" height=\"1\">",
"dc:creator": "John doe",
"guid": "https://medium.com/p/35916b5666be",
"isoDate": "2019-11-19T11:18:44.000Z"
},
{
"creator": "John doe",
"title": "Second blog post for testing…",
"link": "https://medium.com/@doe115237/second-blog-post-for-testing-2f653732d55a?source=rss-af5ade1fb984------2",
"pubDate": "Tue, 19 Nov 2019 08:50:49 GMT",
"content:encoded": "<p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis velit iure debitis voluptatem ducimus nihil laudantium! Doloremque distinctio at inventore?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis velit iure debitis voluptatem ducimus nihil laudantium! Doloremque distinctio at inventore?</p><figure><img alt=\"\" src=\"https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1024/1*1MgMV1m4btqGv3SKf1IlAQ.jpeg\" /><figcaption>dummy image</figcaption></figure><p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis velit iure debitis voluptatem ducimus nihil laudantium! Doloremque distinctio at inventore?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis velit iure debitis voluptatem ducimus nihil laudantium! Doloremque distinctio at inventore?</p><img src=\"https://medium.com/_/stat?event=post.clientViewed&referrerSource=full_rss&postId=2f653732d55a\" width=\"1\" height=\"1\">",
"dc:creator": "John doe",
"guid": "https://medium.com/p/2f653732d55a",
"isoDate": "2019-11-19T08:50:49.000Z"
},
{
"creator": "John doe",
"title": "My first Blog Post",
"link": "https://medium.com/@doe115237/my-first-blog-post-a4578c1bbd22?source=rss-af5ade1fb984------2",
"pubDate": "Tue, 19 Nov 2019 06:26:15 GMT",
"content:encoded": "<p>This is just a test there is nothing to write much blah blah, Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis velit iure debitis voluptatem ducimus nihil laudantium! Doloremque distinctio at inventore?</p><figure><img alt=\"\" src=\"https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/720/1*U6dddRQivNYculO11zw2hQ.png\" /><figcaption>Image 1 for test</figcaption></figure><p><strong>Sub heading 1:</strong></p><p>there is nothing to write much blah blah, Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis velit iure debitis voluptatem ducimus nihil laudantium! Doloremque distinctio at inventore?</p><p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis velit iure debitis voluptatem ducimus nihil laudantium! Doloremque distinctio at inventore?Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis velit iure debitis voluptatem ducimus nihil laudantium! Doloremque distinctio at inventore?</p><iframe src=\"\" width=\"0\" height=\"0\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\"><a href=\"https://medium.com/media/6ca0850549010007ed8c37dec98cf6e9/href\">https://medium.com/media/6ca0850549010007ed8c37dec98cf6e9/href</a></iframe><p>some more code down below:</p><pre>&lt;footer class=”footer text-center py-4&quot;&gt;</pre><pre>&lt;small class=”copyright”&gt;Template Copyright &amp;copy; &lt;a href=”https://themes.3rdwavemedia.com/&quot; target=”_blank”&gt;3rd Wave Media&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</pre><pre>&lt;/footer&gt;</pre><p>another block of code:</p><iframe src=\"\" width=\"0\" height=\"0\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\"><a href=\"https://medium.com/media/ef63bfa9744d1a5e1e6699f4e00c75c8/href\">https://medium.com/media/ef63bfa9744d1a5e1e6699f4e00c75c8/href</a></iframe><figure><img alt=\"\" src=\"https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1024/1*ySQhL7GRAboQU7xHtjYm4A.jpeg\" /></figure><img src=\"https://medium.com/_/stat?event=post.clientViewed&referrerSource=full_rss&postId=a4578c1bbd22\" width=\"1\" height=\"1\">",
"dc:creator": "John doe",
"guid": "https://medium.com/p/a4578c1bbd22",
"isoDate": "2019-11-19T06:26:15.000Z"
}
],
```

Here I would like to access the `content:encoded` in nodejs,

```
app.get('/api/blog', (req, res, next) => {
  (async () => {

    let feed = await parser.parseURL('https://medium.com/feed/@doe115237');
    console.log(feed.title);
    feed.items.forEach(item => {
      console.log(item.title + ':' + item.content:encoded)
    });

  })();

});
```

but the above code gives an error, because I can't use `item.content:encoded`, so any idea how to solve this?

Here's the error message:

```
console.log(item.title + ':' + item.content:encoded)
                                          ^^^^^^^ 
     SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
            at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
            at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
            at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
            at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
            at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
            at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
            at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
            at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
            at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
```

> By the way here I'm using rss-parser package to convert the medium
>   blog's rss feeds to json data

Comment: What's the error u r getting?? Also you can try for `item['content:encoded']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need IIFE, access odd key the other way, remove breaking bits and res.send.

So essentially removing a few lines:

```
app.get('/api/blog', async(req, res, next) => {
  let feed = await parser.parseURL('https://medium.com/feed/@doe115237');
  feed.items.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item.title + ':' + item['content:encoded'])
  });

  res.send(); // dont leave express hanging
});
```